# If $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\left|a_n\right|$ diverges, Why it means that $\:\lim _{n\to \infty }\left|a_n\right|$ $\ne 0$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

consider $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:a_n$.
(No one say it positive series).

now, we look at this: $\frac{\left | a_{n+1} \right |}{\left | a_{n} \right |} \rightarrow  L$

and L>1:

If  $\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\left|a_n\right|$ diverges, Why it means that $\:\lim _{n\to \infty }\left|a_n\right|$ $\ne 0$ ?

Comment: Are consider $\sum a_n$ as a convergent series? It the case the series $\sum a_n$ converge then $a_n \rightarrow 0$ implies that $|a_n| \rightarrow 0$

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't imply that.  Take $a_n=\frac{1}{n+1}$.  Then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty{|a_n|}$ diverges but certainly $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{|a_n|}=0$.

ANSWER TO THE EDITED QUESTION:

We must assume that $a_n\neq 0$ for all $n$, as otherwise $\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}$ is undefined.

Since $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}}=L$, it follows that for a given $\epsilon>0$ with $L-\epsilon>1$ there is $N$ such that for every $n>N$ we have $L-\epsilon<\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}<L+\epsilon$.  Then $(L-\epsilon)|a_n|<|a_{n+1}|<(L+\epsilon)|a_n|$.

This leads to $(L-\epsilon)|a_{n-1}|<|a_n|$, so we have $(L-\epsilon)^2|a_{n-1}|<|a_{n+1}|$, and we can continue this to deduce $(L-\epsilon)^{n}|a_0|<|a_{n}|$.  Since $L-\epsilon>1$ we conclude that 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{|a_n|}\geq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{(L-\epsilon)^n|a_0|}>0$$

Comment: In this case we would have L = 1 in the limit test. The question states that L > 1

Comment: When I answered the question there was no mention of (what can be assumed to be) the ratio test.

Answer (score 3):

That's not the case. $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac 1n$ diverges and $\lim\frac1n=0$.

Comment: In this case we would have L = 1 in the limit test. The question states that L > 1

Comment: The question was edited after I answered.

Answer (score 3):

If $\left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|\to L>1$, this means that for some $N$ we have
$$\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}\ge c>1 \quad\text{for all }n\ge N.$$ This in turn means that
$|a_n|\ge c^{n-N}|a_N|$ for all $n\ge N$. So, in fact, $|a_n|\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

This question only makes sense if we assume $a_n \ne 0$ for all $n$.

If $\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_{n}|} \to L > 1$, then there exists $N$ such that for all $n > N$, $\frac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_{n}|} > 1$. But $|a_n| = \frac{|a_{n}|}{|a_{n-1}|} \frac{|a_{n-1}|}{|a_{n-2}|}\ldots\frac{|a_{N+1 }|}{|a_{N}|} |a_N| > |a_N| > 0$ for all $n > N$ so $a_n \nrightarrow 0$

Comment: I believe you mean to write $|a_n|=\cdots$.